# Why does Julia have `Base.invokelatest`?

Tags: julia

It seems like it just calls the function.
When is it needed?
It seems much slower than calling the function directly.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following example,
Where a function `bar` uses `@eval` to redefine `foo` before calling it

```
julia> foo() = 1
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> function bar()
           @eval foo() = 2  # remember @eval runs at global scope
           foo()
       end
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar()
1   # Got old version

julia> function bar2()
           @eval foo() = 3  # remember @eval runs at global scope
           Base.invokelatest(foo,)
       end
bar2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar2()
3
```

Because by the time `bar` calls `foo`
`bar` has by its nature already been compiled,
and so `foo` has been optimized as a static call.
(probably inlined even in this case).

So `bar` can’t see the newly overwritten `foo` that was created via `@eval`

It is slower because it prevents the call compiling down to a static dispatch.

Generally you should never need this 
This kinda code is not good.
Try and avoid using `@eval` inside functions.
It is hard to reason about.

Comment: Can this happen in any case where `eval` is not used?

Comment: Maybe some other similar operations to `eval`.
I susepct `include`, and `@everywhere`.